# Spark - how to get distinct values with their count

Tags: apache-spark

If I have a dataset like this:

```
name | food    | drink  | dollars
==================================
John | salad   | water  | 1
Dave | salad   | soda   | 2
John | burger  | water  | 5
John | burger  | soda   | 1
```

How do I get the following result in Spark (Scala):

```
name | food_count                | drink_count             | total_dollars
==========================================================================
John | [(salad, 1), (burger, 2)] | [(water, 2), (soda, 1)] | 7
Dave | [(salad, 1)]              | [(soda, 1)]             | 2
```

Not sure which aggregate function to apply after `groupBy("name")`.
Do I need to write a UADF?
Feels like it's a common enough problem, so I was hoping there is a solution using built-in functions.

Comment: you can use cube and then you need to join by name and you will get answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spark you can try with [Multi-Dimensional Aggregation](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-multi-dimensional-aggregation.html)  `cube` count and then use `collect_list`:

```
scala>  var df =Seq(("John" , "salad"   , "water", 1),("Dave" , "salad"   , "soda" , 2),("John" , "burger"  , "water", 5),("John" , "burger"  , "soda" , 1)).toDF("name","food","drink","dollar")

scala> var testing  = df.cube("name", "food","drink").count()
scala> var drinks_df =testing.filter(col("food").isNotNull).groupBy("name","drink").agg(struct(col("drink"),sum("count")).as("drink_count")).na.drop.groupBy("name").agg(collect_list("drink_count").as("drink_count")).join(df.groupBy("name").agg(sum("dollar").as("dollars_sum")),Seq("name"),"left").withColumnRenamed("name","name1")

scala> var fooddf1 = testing.filter(col("drink").isNotNull).groupBy("name","food").agg(struct(col("food"),sum("count")).as("food_count")).na.drop.groupBy("name").agg(collect_list("food_count").as("food_count"))

scala> fooddf1.join(drinks_df,col("name1")===col("name"),"left").drop("name1").show(false)
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+            
|name|food_count               |drink_count            |dollars_sum|
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|Dave|[[salad, 1]]             |[[soda, 1]]            |2          |
|John|[[salad, 1], [burger, 2]]|[[water, 2], [soda, 1]]|7          |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

With the help of multi-dimension function, you can count a row with a different group

Comment: Hi Mahesh!
Sorry, I simplified my example too much - in a real dataset I have multiple columns for which I need to get this kind of counts - I updated the question to reflect that.
I'd like to be able to group just by name and then do counts for some of the columns and other aggregations for other columns.